# Is it possible to use a variable to store input value(s) and then use the variable to invoke hash table value(s) using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-5.1

I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to do but maybe the code will help you understand.
I might get a few terms wrong, I'm still learning.

I was not unable to find any documentation that would help my case.
I feel like I'm complicating things and I could just use a lot of "if" statements but this seemed to be a way more efficient way (if it's possible) for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am trying to invoke multiple Hash values with the "foreach" statement using the "read-host" inputs.

```
#Hash
$AppGroupsHash = @{
1 = "AppADGroup1" 
2 = "AppADGroup2" 
3 = "AppADGroup3" 
4 = "AppADGroup4" 
}

$AppGroups = $AppGroupsHash.Values -as [string[]]

#write-host for flair and choices to choose from.
Write-Host "`n1 = AppADGroup1`n2 = AppADGroup1`n3 = AppADGroup1`n4 = AppADGroup1`n  " -ForegroundColor Yellow

#User input value(s) for the required task
#Not sure if [string] is necessary in front of $AppGroupsKeys 
[string]$AppGroupsKeys = Read-Host "Enter App Hash values (1 - 2 - 3 - 4) (No space, delimit with ';') "

foreach ($AppGroupsKey in $AppGroupsKeys.split(';')) 
{
        if ($AppGroupsHash.Keys -ccontains $AppGroupsKey) 
        {
        #To test if it will print the values I'm trying to invoke
        echo $AppGroupsKey 

        #This is where I'm getting into trouble
        $AppGroupsHash.($AppGroupsKey) 
        } 
}
```

When I run it. This is what I get,  **Read-Host Values: 1;3;4** :

```
#These are the values being echoed but the "$AppGroupsHash.($AppGroupsKey)" does not work
1
3
4
```

What it should print out:

```
#Test "echo values"
1
3
4 

#The "values" I want
AppADGroup1
AppADGroup3
AppADGroup4
```

I want to use the variables I've inputted as the Keys that are stored in the hash so that I can invoke those values, these will be eventually used to add users to those groups based on their requirements.

This is what I tried:

```
foreach ($AppGroupsKey in $AppGroupsKeys.split(';')) 
{
        if ($AppGroupsHash.Keys -ccontains $AppGroupsKey) 
        {
        #To test if it will print the values I'm trying to invoke
        echo $AppGroupsKey 

        #This is where I'm getting into trouble
        write-host "$AppGroupsHash.$AppGroupsKey;"
        } 
}
```

Output:

```
1
System.Collections.Hashtable.1;
2
System.Collections.Hashtable.2;
4
System.Collections.Hashtable.4;
```

I feel like it's possible but I also feel like I'm missing some sort of secret syntax for this to work.

Is it possible what I want to accomplish or should I try Arrays or just a bunch of "if" statements?

Comment: I'll give you a hint that might help you understand and fix the issue yourself :) // try `$AppGroupsHash.'1'` and then try `$AppGroupsHash.1` (note this one has no quotes), lastly try `$AppGroupsHash.[int]'1'`

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, This one worked for me: `$AppGroupsHash.[int]$AppGroupsKey` displays all the values I wanted to pull.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out, as best advise I can give you, use strings instead of integers for your hashtable keys (simply quote them) then you wouldn't have a need to cast `[int]`